# Links are not visible when looking through other dimension than my computers

Tags: html, css, media-queries

The Links in my navigation bar are disappearing when I am look at my website through a other dimension like an iPhone display. I tried to fix it even with some settings in the media section, but in vain. Is it because of the whole code or due to a specific section? I need some help here.
Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lemak</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <header>
    <div class = "container">
        <nav class = "navbar">
           <a href = "/"  class = "nav-branding">LEMAK</a> 
           <ul class = nav-menu>
            <li class = "nav-link"><a href = "/">ÜBER UNS</a></li>
            <li class = "nav-link"><a href = "/">KONTAKT</a></li>
            <li class = "nav-link"> <a href = "/">IMPRESSUM</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

     <div id = "picture-container">
        <div class = "picture"></div>
        <div class = "picture"></div>
     </div>

</body>
</html>





  * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    body {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    header {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%
    }
    
    li {
        list-style: none;
    
    }
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .container {
        width: 1280px;
        margin: auto;
        
    }
    
    .navbar, .navbar a {
        color: black;
    }
    
    
    .navbar{
        width: 95%;
        margin: auto;
        min-height: 70px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        
    }
    
    .nav-menu{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        gap: 3.75rem;
    }
    
    
    
    .nav-branding{
        font-size: 2 rem; 
    }
    
    @media(max-width: 1280px) {
        .container {
            width: 1280px;
        }
    }
    
    /* pcitures*/
    #picture-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between; /* Horizontale Ausrichtung beibehalten */
    }
    
    .picture {
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 80vh;
        width: 50%;
    }
    
    @media(max-width: 768px) {
        #picture-container {
            flex-direction: column; /* Bei kleineren Bildschirmen vertikal anordnen */
        }
        
        .picture {
            width: 100%; /* Auf volle Breite des Containers ändern */
        }
    
    
      
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a closing tag for you header section </header>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from the line of code below, you set a fixed width for the `.container` class, which contains your navigation bar. This fixed width is causing your navigation bar to overflow and become inaccessible on smaller screens.

```
    @media(max-width: 1280px) {
        .container {
            width: 1280px;
        }
    }
```

To fix this issue, you should make your navigation bar responsive by using percentage-based widths instead of fixed widths.

```
 @media (max-width: 1280px) {
        .container {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
```

Additionally, don't forget to add the closing tag for your header section `</header>`